# Why don't Tencent Weibo and Baidu Tieba links work?

Tags: url, social-networking, weibo

The following Chinese social media post links have been constructed in the correct format, but neither of them is working:

[http://v.t.qq.com/share/share.php?url=https://hejuu.com/bonus/0/tencent&title=hejuu.com整套出租，单间出租，出售房产&pic=http://hejuu.com/pages/images/social.png](http://v.t.qq.com/share/share.php?url=https://hejuu.com/bonus/0/tencent&title=hejuu.com%E6%95%B4%E5%A5%97%E5%87%BA%E7%A7%9F%EF%BC%8C%E5%8D%95%E9%97%B4%E5%87%BA%E7%A7%9F%EF%BC%8C%E5%87%BA%E5%94%AE%E6%88%BF%E4%BA%A7&pic=http://hejuu.com/pages/images/social.png)

[http://tieba.baidu.com/f/commit/share/openShareApi?url=https://hejuu.com/bonus/0/tieba&title=hejuu.com整套出租，单间出租，出售房产&desc=&pic=http://hejuu.com/pages/images/social.png](http://tieba.baidu.com/f/commit/share/openShareApi?url=https://hejuu.com/bonus/0/tieba&title=hejuu.com%E6%95%B4%E5%A5%97%E5%87%BA%E7%A7%9F%EF%BC%8C%E5%8D%95%E9%97%B4%E5%87%BA%E7%A7%9F%EF%BC%8C%E5%87%BA%E5%94%AE%E6%88%BF%E4%BA%A7&desc=&pic=http://hejuu.com/pages/images/social.png)

I've tried:

- Encoding the query string parameters
- Changing the submission URL to use HTTP instead of HTTPS
- Getting someone in China to test the URL inside the firewall

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I managed to figure out Tieba, they don't like SSL and they don't support redirects, so this works (I had to disable mandatory SSL on my front page): http://tieba.baidu.com/f/commit/share/openShareApi?url=http://hejuu.com&title=hejuu.com&desc=&pic=http://hejuu.com/pages/images/social.png

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue with the Tencent share URL? I can't find any information about why this stopped working or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Tencent QQ resolves to 0.0.0.1 (even inside mainland-China), so the feature is deliberately broken.

The Baidu links appears to work now, however.